# HDMI to VGA converter connection errors

Tags: xorg, multiple-monitors, hdmi, xrandr, vga

I'm getting a weird error when connecting my VGA monitor via an [Aukey HDMI to VGA adapter](https://www.aukey.com/products/hdmi-to-vga-adapter) to my laptop's HDMI port:

Whether a connection can be established or not (i.e. on startup, when opening system settings or when running `xrandr --query`) is apparently determined by pure chance; when running `xrandr --query` multiple times consecutively, it sometimes prints `HDMI-1 disconnected` and sometimes `HDMI-1 connected`. But only when it's connected, the monitor is actually working and extends my desktop (this is the expected behavior).

My laptop (later named "Laptop A") is an Acer Aspire VN7-571G-52EP. A Dell XPS 15 ("Laptop B") always connected without problems (running `xrandr` was not needed to make the monitor work).

I tried different combinations:

```
Computer | OS                      | Connection  | Monitor          | Result
=====================================================================
Laptop A | Ubuntu 17.10            | Converter A | Monitor A (VGA)  | not working
Laptop A | Ubuntu 17.10            | Converter A | Monitor B (VGA)  | not working
Laptop A | Ubuntu 17.10            | HDMI cable  | Monitor C (HDMI) | working
Laptop A | Ubuntu 17.10            | Converter B | Monitor A (VGA)  | not working
Laptop A | Windows 10              | Converter A | Monitor A (VGA)  | working
Laptop A | KDE Neon (Xenial)       | Converter A | Monitor A (VGA)  | not working
         | Live image 20180113     |             |                  | 
Laptop B | KDE Neon (Xenial)       | Converter A | Monitor A (VGA)  | working
         | Up-to-date installation |             |                  |
```

Some notes:

- "not working" means that weird random connection error, "working" means that there were no connection errors (plug and play)
- Converters A/B are different devices of the same model

These combinations prove that it must be a software problem.

Both laptops have both an intel and an Nvidia graphics card with up-to-date proprietary Nvidia drivers installed (no bumblebee and never tried to enable Nvidia Optimus). Laptop B uses the intel GPU (controllable via `nvidia-settings`). For Laptop A, the problem couldn't be resolved by using either the intel or Nvidia GPU (using Ubuntu 17.10).

I also tried using Wayland instead of X.Org (on Laptop A), but it never connected to my monitor. Running `xrandr` didn't help then.

**Does anybody have an idea what causes this strange behavior and how to fix it?**

Attached logs:

- **`xrandr --current --version`** (snippet) when the monitor is disconnected

  https://pastebin.com/rTZnwde7
- **`xrandr --current --version`** (snippet) when the monitor is connected

  https://pastebin.com/sFFdqbX7
- **`lspci -v`**

  https://pastebin.com/3qgJdib4

Comment: If no one finds an answer, ping me before the bounty expires, please?  Then I'll undelete so the bounty doesn't go to nowhere...

Comment: Sounds like either a hardware problem or a bug report.

Comment: @Fabby As per your request, this bounty ends tomorrow with no accepted answers...

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  Answer undeleted and your question upvoted to undo some of the -50 damage.

Comment: Felix, I feel guilty for accepting your bounty.  If you post any decent answer here on this site, I'll return it.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, I've had this before as well and it sometimes happens on cheap low-end laptops with cheap non-powered adapters.

I've never had this happen with externally powered ones so it's a hardware problem on the Acer that was probably solved in the Windows driver (more power output to the port) that hasn't found its way into the Linux driver yet.

Your solutions are:

- file a bug with both Intel and nVidia
- buy an externally powered HDMI to VGA adapter for the Acer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I forgot to mention that my converter is an active one and has a micro USB slot. Connecting it to a (strong) power source didn't change the weird behavior, though. (Laptop B didn't need an external power source for the converter to work.)

My laptop wasn't even cheap, by the way ...

Comment: OK, read the specs: the Aukey HDMI to VGA adapter looks like a non-powered one to me...  How does it get its power?  From an additional USB Port or from an external power supply? (The spec sheet is mediocre). Does the Acer have a high-power USB slot? (E.g. to charge phones faster or plug in power-hungry devices like large HDDs).  If yes, try that one.

Comment: I connected the converter's micro USB slot with an external power supply (a regular one to charge phones). I don't have a high-power USB slot.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the website for the HDMI to VGA converter you purchased and didn't get a good feeling at level of support. You might want to consider purchasing this [Acer HDMI to VGA adapter](https://www.cdw.com/product/Acer-HDMI-to-VGA-Converter-video-converter-white/3826319) instead:

[image: acer hdmi to vga adapter]

You can try asking Acer **before** purchase purchase if it works with Linux. **After** purchase you have two possible support channels:

- From reputable manufacturer: **Acer**
- From reputable retailer: **CDW**

Of course you can always get support from forums where you are more likely to find other Acer users rather than AUKEY users.

Personally I haven't used this kind of converter. I have used the reverse type of VGA to HDMI self-powered converter without any real problems other than normal initial setup challenges with `xrandr`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I don't think my converter is wrong as it works perfectly on Laptop A with Windows and on Laptop B even with Ubuntu. Furthermore, the Acer adapter doesn't has a microphone output ...